# Pandas object from Pickle - Type not known by the IDE

Tags: python, pandas, types, ide, pickle

In Python, using the IDE PyCharm, when I type:

```
df = some_function_returning_a_dataframe()
```

Then the IDE recognise that df is a Pandas Dataframe and give me helpful suggestions when I later type in the code.

But, if I import a dataframe from a Pickle, via :

```
df = pandas.read_pickle("dump.pkl")
```

Then the IDE does not recognise the type of df and does not help me any more.
I assume that the IDE does not know the type before reading the pickle.

Is there any way to counter that?

Comment: What if you use `df = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.read_pickle("dump.pkl"))`?

Comment: @unutbu : That's it, thanks !
But please enter it as an answer, so that I can validate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(pandas.read_pickle("dump.pkl"))
```

to help PyCharm know `df` is a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You can also `assert` the type in line, or put the unpickling in a function with a hinted return type (`:rtype: pd.Dataframe`), and PyCharm will recognize it